# acess class attribute in another file

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

I have a question about accessing attribute in class

t1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import t2

class A:
        flag = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
        t2.f()
        print(A.flag)
```

t2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import t1

def f():
        t1.A.flag = True
        print(t1.A.flag)
```

excute Result:

```
# ./t1.py
True
False
```

I expect that result has to be True, True.

Are A.flag in t1.py and t1.A.flag in t2.py diffrent?

What happends in python when excute this code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
./t1.py
```

you're executing the `t1.py` file, but it's not executed as the `t1` module. It's considered to be the `__main__` module. (This is what that `if __name__ == '__main__'` line checks for.) That means that when this line:

```
import t1
```

in `t2.py` tries to import `t1`, Python starts executing the `t1.py` file *again* to create the `t1` module. You end up with two versions of the `A` class, one being `__main__.A` and one being `t1.A`. The modification to `t1.A` doesn't do anything to `__main__.A`, because even though they came from the same code in the same file, they're not the same class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed two different objects (explained very well in [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38649968/5827958)).  If you want `t2` to use the same object, you need to tell Python that you are actually importing the same module that is importing `t2`.  To do that, import `__main__` instead:

```
import __main__

def f():
    __main__.A.flag = True
    print(__main__.A.flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out yourself:

## t1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('t1 has started')
logger.debug('t2 is being imported')
import t2

logger.debug('A is being "compiled"')
class A:
    flag = False
logger.debug('ID A: %r', id(A))
logger.debug('ID A.flag %r', id(A.flag))

logger.debug('What is __name__? %r', __name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.debug('__name__ was "__main__"')
    logger.debug('Calling t2.f()')
    t2.f()
    logger.debug('t2.f() was called')
    logger.debug('ID A.flag: %r', id(A.flag))
    print(A.flag)
```

## t2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('t2 is being imported')

logger.debug('t2 is now importing t1')
import t1

def f():
    logger.debug('f is being called')
    t1.A.flag = True
    logger.debug('ID t1: %r', id(t1))
    logger.debug('ID t1.A: %r', id(t1.A))
    logger.debug('ID t1.A.flag: %r', id(t1.A.flag))
    print(t1.A.flag)
```

## My output

<sup><sub>I'm splitting this up with comments</sub></sup>

```
DEBUG:__main__:t1 has started
DEBUG:__main__:t2 is being imported
DEBUG:t2:t2 is being imported
DEBUG:t2:t2 is now importing t1
```

As you can see, the first time around (as others have mentioned) `t1` actually has the name of `__main__`. It tries importing `t2`, but immediately `t2` tries importing `t1`.

```
DEBUG:t1:t1 has started
DEBUG:t1:t2 is being imported
```

You can see that none of the `t2` logging statements run. That's because Python caches imported modules, so it first looks in the cache for `t2` and says, "Ahah! I've already imported this guy, I just need to return it. Here you go, then!"

```
DEBUG:t1:A is being "compiled"
DEBUG:t1:ID A: 140377934341704
DEBUG:t1:ID A.flag 4312040768
DEBUG:t1:What is __name__? 't1'
```

So, you'll notice that now it has made its way through importing `t1`. And `t2`

```
DEBUG:t2:t2 is done being imported
```

Execution continues back in the `__main__` `t1`

```
DEBUG:__main__:A is being "compiled"
DEBUG:__main__:ID A: 140377934344360
DEBUG:__main__:ID A.flag 4312040768
```

Notice that the `id` for this `A` and `A.flag` are different!

```
DEBUG:__main__:What is __name__? '__main__'
DEBUG:__main__:__name__ was "__main__"
DEBUG:__main__:Calling t2.f()
DEBUG:t2:f is being called
DEBUG:t2:ID t1: 4317998840
DEBUG:t2:ID t1.A: 140377934341704
DEBUG:t2:ID t1.A.flag: 4312040736
```

Notice again, that these `id`s match `t1.A`'s, and not `__main__.A`s.

```
True
DEBUG:__main__:t2.f() was called
DEBUG:__main__:ID A.flag: 4312040768
False
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I can see how this can be a little confusing but it is basically a question of namespaces along with the distinction that the `__main__` namespace is not considered as part of the list of imported modules. This allows the file that is the point of execution (and thus occupying the `__main__` namespace) to also be imported as a module. On the other hand, if the same module is imported more than once, the interpreter will simply let all the different imports point to the same memory location

Because of this, in the code you are showing above, you actually have two distinct versions of `A`: you have `__main__.A` and you have `__main__.t2.t1.A`. The second one comes about because `__main__`is importing `t2` which in turn is importing `t1` as a module.

When you are running `t2.f()`, you are setting `__main__.t2.t1.A.flag = True` and then printing it. Subsequently, when you call `print(A.flag)`, you are printing the value in `__main__.A.flag`, which was never changed.

I hope that makes at least a little sense.

A friend of mine always said that computer science is an experimental science.
Let's invoke the debugger.

I add a `pdb.set_trace()` to the execution and `t1.py` now looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import t2

class A:
        flag = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    t2.f()
    print(A.flag)
```

And this is what we get:

```
$ python t1.py
> /Users/martin/git/temp/t1.py(9)<module>()
-> t2.f()
(Pdb) A
<class __main__.A at 0x10ec9ba78>
(Pdb) t2.t1.A
<class t1.A at 0x10ec9ba10>
(Pdb)
```

Please note that the `A` have separate memory locations associated.

Comment: Circular imports not involving `__main__` don't trigger this behavior. If circular imports always resulted in reexecution of the reimported modules, you'd get a stack overflow due to infinite recursive imports. `__main__` is crucial here.

Comment: That is true, it does treat `__main__` differently in that respect. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.